# Probability without knowing the overall number of things in the bag

Tags: probability

I have a question and no idea how to approach it. If there are seven red counters in a bag, the rest of the counters in the bag are blue. There are more blue than red counters in the bag. Two are to be taken at random from the bag. The probability that there will be one counter of each colour is 7/15. Work out the total number of counters in the bag before any counters are taken from the bag. How should I do this?

Comment: I think the expression here has to be significantly updated so people can understand your problem.

Comment: This is a bit hard to read...but I assume you should assign an unknown $N$ to the number of blue balls and then, as a function of $N$ compute the probability of drawing mixed colors.  Setting this equal to $\frac 7{15}$ should let you solve for $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $N$ red counters at the start. The prob of drawing one of each colour is $$\frac{2\cdot7\cdot N}{(N+7)(N+6)}=\frac{7}{15}$$ So $(N-3)(N-14)=0$. But we are given $N>7$, so $N=14$.